# Java regex library with recursion support

Tags: java, regex, recursive-regex

I am looking for a Java regexp lib with support for recursion, like:

```
"<a+(?0)>"
```

JDK does not support it, ORO does neither.

Anyone knows about such?

Thanks,
Ondra

Edit: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php

And I need it for this expression:

`(?:mUi)^/--++ *+(.*)(?: *(?<= |^)\\.((?:\\([^)\\n]+\\)|\\[[^\\]\\n]+\\]|\\{[^}\\n]+\\}|<>|>|=|<){1,4}?))?$((?:\\n.*+)*)(?:\\n(?0)|\\n\\\\--.*$|\\z)`

Comment: Not to be a pedant but technically once a regex supports this it's no longer a regex because it's no longer regular. By this it's no longer a DFA (deterministic finite automaton) and is instead a context-free grammar (pushdown automaton). Not that that really answers your question. :)

Comment: Therefore, you should look to ANTLR.

Comment: Curious, what is the expected behavior of that expression?

Comment: PSpeed << (?n) acts like you applied the n-th group of the regex again - thus, (?0) applies the whole regexp again. Which causes it to be context-aware, so it matches <a<aa>>, but not <a<aa>.

Comment: cletus << There's no conflict - I want a regexp lib with support for recursion. I did not say that it should only accept regular expressions. But thanks for your smart note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: There's none. I could possibly modify the JDK's `java.util.regex`.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stevesoft Pat](http://www.javaregex.com/home.html) library has some recursive-matching capability (documented [here](http://www.javaregex.com/tutorial6.html)), but that feature probably isn't as useful as you expect it to be.  If recursive matching is that important to you, you should probably be using a real parser instead of regexes.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more powerful, like the PHP PCRE has (docs added in the question).

The DIY option seems like the only one.